# StackOverFlow exception while setting a property via the construction

Tags: c#, .net, stack-overflow

I have a simple class model with a single property inside.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UF uf = new UF(5);
        }
    }
}

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class UF
    {
        public UF(int N)
        {
            this.n = N;
            Console.WriteLine(this.n);
        }

        private int n
        {
            get => n;

            set
            {
                if (value <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value));
                else
                {
                    n = value;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Who can explain to me why after class initialization via my constructor I am having the StackOverflow exception on the setter property?

Comment: You have a property called `n` and inside the setter for that property you set the property called `n`. Have a think about what happens if you do that. You might consider having a private backing field for that property.

Comment: You recall n property from n

Comment: Please always show the full error/exception message for this kind of "Why this code is not working?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your exception comes from here :

```
n = value;
```

You have declared your property with the name of `n` and constantly tries to rewrite its value. Try renaming your property to something like `N` and it should be fine.

```
class UF
{
    public UF(int N)
    {
        this._n = N;
        Console.WriteLine(this.n);
    }

    int _n;
    private int N
    {
        get => _n;

        set
        {
            if (value <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value));
            else
            {
                _n = value;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thx, I got it :)

Answer (score 3):

You are setting n inside your setter which again calls the setter of n doing the same thing over and over again until your callstack is full.

You could instead try to implement a public porperty N and a private field n.
And then set the field from your properties' setter:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UF uf = new UF(5);

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}

class UF
{
    private int n;

    public UF(int N)
    {
        this.n = N;
        Console.WriteLine(this.n);
    }

    public int N
    {
        get => n;

        set
        {
            if (value <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value));
            else
            {
                n = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```